# passing a input file as a parameter

Tags: java, string, methods, input

I really need help on my java project. My problem is that I am new to Java and I can't figure out how to pass a input file in java.

I need to open a .dat file, read the file, and set it as a named constant so I can pass it to other methods as a string.

For example I want to open myFle.dat in my beginning method and pass it to a method like this so I can work with it their

```
doMethod(fileString);
```

If possible talk simple java to me because I am new to this.

Comment: [API docs for the java.io package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: This isn't very clear. What do you mean by "open the file"?

Comment: pass the path of the file as argument to the method and in the method get your file

Comment: I would like to open it and read the file at first, then set it to a named constant so i can pass it to other methods as a string.

Comment: pragnani can you post a quick example

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a `Stream` to the `File` and read that into a `StringBuilder` , here is a simple example:

```
final File file = new File("/path/to/my/file.txt");
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")) {
    final CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
    while (reader.read(cb) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append(cb.flip());
        cb.clear();
    }
}
final String fileAsString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

This assumes the file is in "UTF-8" encoding. The code uses the Java 7 try-with-resources construct to close the `Reader` when you're done with it. Otherwise you would need to use a try-finally.